# CSVReader and android

Tags: android, csv, file-io

I want to read in the data from a csv-file and store it into a database. This is how I saved the csv-file (this works without errors - just to show where and how the file is stored which I plan to read with CSVreader):

```
synchronized public void readFromUrl(String url, String outputFile, Context context) throws FileNotFoundException {
        URL downloadLink = null;
        try {
            downloadLink = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
                        in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(downloadLink.openStream(), "UTF8"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream fstream = context.openFileOutput(outputFile,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fstream);

        Log.d(TAG, "BufferedReader "+in); 
        String inputLine = null;
        try {
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                out.write(inputLine+"\n");
                //logger.debug("DOWNLOADED: "+inputLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fstream.close();
            out.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My code so far for reading the csv file:

```
public void readInCSVFile(String filename, Context context) throws IOException {
        IDbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(); ; 
        CSVReader products = null;

        products = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(filename)));
```

I get a NoClassDefFoundError exception.

I have the opencsv.jar in the Referenced libraries of my android project.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your project in the Eclipse IDE? If yes, then have a look whether the lib (opencsv.jar) is set in the "project properties->Java Build Path->Libraries" *and* that it is checked in the tab: "Order and Export" too. Under "Order and Export" move the lib to the top of the list.
Then clean and rebuild.

PS: If this does not help, then please provide the complete stacktrace of the error.